# How can I get unlimited population in Age of Empires IV?

Tags: mods, age-of-empires-iv

I saw a video on AoE 4 with unlimited population:

[image]

How can I get unlimited population in Age of Empires IV?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it would look exactly same, but there is [WeMod](https://www.wemod.com/cheats/age-of-empires-iv-trainers) that allows you to change some things via cheats.

> The “reset current population” cheat resets your population number back to 0, so you can circumvent the population cap by resetting your population number whenever you hit the cap.